# Rails 5: Delete button link_to did not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a delete `link_to` in Rails 5 but for some reason. It did not work.

Basically, I have boot up the user table via the devise configuration or set up.

This will work per single account.

This time I am trying to create a page or pages that will be shown only specifically for users with admin role only.

So what I did is I created another controller for controller's list and then on my `routes.rb` I place this:

```
 get 'dashboard/users-list', to: 'users#index'
```

Then inside my `app/views/users/index.html.erb` I have place the following:

```
  <section class="form-contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto center-box">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h2 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center font-weight-bold">Users List</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">


<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
       <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= user.id %></th>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user">Edit</button>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete user?"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-user" %>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Notice the delete part:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete user?"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
```

When I reload this its throwing a 'users_path not working` error.

Here's my `users` controller btw:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_contact, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
    @users = User.all
   end 

   def edit
   end

   def update
   end

   def destroy
     @user.destroy
   end 

   private

   def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

   def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :user_avatar, :password)
  end
end
```

While I got successful on listing all the user, the delete button won't even work so I can delete a particular user inside. Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in your controller or did you make a copy/paste mistake?

Changing

```
before_action :set_contact, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

to

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

this can work maybe.